# create directory on fly during application deployment or first request to application.

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I All,
I have been stuck in this issue for a week now.I want the directory to be created in the root of my project when my application runs in IIS.But since IIS user account can't be given full permission in the root directory , i get the access denied error while trying to create directory.I tried to find a work around by keeping the images in App_Data folder but does not look like a good approach as per the post  [enter link description here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/118826/asp-net-development-server-cannot-access-images-from-app-data-directory)

I need to create the folder on fly when the request comes to the application for the first time without getting access denied error.It is also ok if i am able to create directory with permission during deployment.
What is the best approach for the above problem to solve,
Thanks S.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the information in your link. It's true that the `browser` shouldn't have access to the App_Data folder, but in your case it's the `server`, your ASP.NET code that does this.

If this scenario is for letting user upload and download files, and you have sensitive files in the app_data folder, create a dedicated folder for your purpose instead let's say /Uploads.
Create this folder in your project directly and deploy it to your destination web server.
Give the app pool account read/write permissions, and that should do it.
Minimize the number of folders that the app pool account has write permissions to.

If you create a folder `/wwwroot/Uploads` and give the app pool account full permission to Uploads only, it's not necessary to have full permissions on the root level. The app can create folders dynamically in the `/Uploads` folder.

Comment: Thanks magnus for quick response.But there is one instance where i need to be able to access the image via browser.That is when i upload the images i should be able to preview the images.I am using the url to the image(returned as json result) for accomplishing that purpose.So since the browser does not have the access to App_Data folder i am not able to  display the image via image path which was returned via json.Is there any way to return image via json.I did some googling but of to no result till now.:(

Comment: Ok, well then simply create a dedicated folder, let's say /Uploads instead of using App_Data. Give the application pool account read/write permissions to that new folder and that should do it.

Comment: Thanks again,In order  to do so application pool account need to be give full control to the root directory for directory create.This is not acceptable to my client.Is there any way out?

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't do that, and there is no need. See my updated answer.

Comment: Hi Magnus,the problem is i am not able to create directory onfly without giving the application pool account full permission to the root,that is the problem.OR as a workaround is it possible to create directory with permission during deployment.The directory can,t be created manually it needs to be created onfly,Thanks

Comment: That is not true. An account can have full permissions on \root\sub without have full permissions on \root. Create \root\sub for your app manually, give full permissions to \root\sub and let the app create as many folders as it needs in \root\sub on the fly.